# Enabling clipboard+ in vim

Tags: vim, clipboard

How do I enable the `clipboard+` feature in Vim?

All questions related to copy pasting from Vim to the OS clipboard specify that this feature must be enabled.

```
vim --version | grep "clipboard"
```

returns

```
-clipboard -xterm_clipboard
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile it with `./configure --enable=clipboard`. If you are using Vim bundled by your distribution then you need to check which one provides integration with it (on Debian it is `vim-gtk` IIRC).

Comment: There is also [fauxClip](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/fauxClip) if you can not compile your own vim

Comment: Okay, so I executed  `./configure --enable=clipboard` in src directory. However it returns error: `configure: error: unrecognized option: --enable=clipboard
Try auto/configure --help' for more information`. I also tried `./configure --enable-clipboard=yes`. It returned this error:
 `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-clipboard`.

Comment: I found a workaround. I compiled with flag `--with-features=huge` and it has clipboard support. However it is weird that I couldn't choose to compile with only specified features. Really looked through all readme and install files but couldn't find any useful information. Only `./configure --help` tells that you can enable certain features but doesn't specify the whole list of features. Any ideas where could I ask if this list exist or if somebody could create this kind of a list?